# NameError: name 'AdAccount' is not defined

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I can't get sample code from github to work. I updated imports but still I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 34, in 
>       my_account = AdAccount.get_my_account()
>   NameError: name 'AdAccount' is not defined

```
from facebookads.session import FacebookSession
from facebookads import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.helpers import *
from facebookads.adobjects import *

import ad_creation_utils
import json
import os

this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_filename = os.path.join(this_dir, 'config.json')

config_file = open(config_filename)
config = json.load(config_file)
config_file.close()

### Setup session and api objects
session = FacebookSession(
    config['app_id'],
    config['app_secret'],
    config['access_token'],
)
api = FacebookAdsApi(session)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)

    # Get my account (first account associated with the user associated with the
    #                 session of the default api)
    my_account = AdAccount.get_my_account()

    print('**** Creating ad...')

    # Create my ad
    my_ad = ad_creation_utils.create_website_clicks_ad(
        account=my_account,

        name="Visit Seattle",
        country='US',

        title="Visit Seattle",                             # How it looks
        body="Beautiful Puget Sound.",
        url="http://www.seattle.gov/visiting/",
        image_path=os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__),
            os.pardir,
            'image.png'
        ),

        bid_type=AdSet.BidType.cpm,
        bid_info={AdSet.Field.BidInfo.impressions: 53},  # $0.53 / thousand
        daily_budget=1000,  # $10.00 per day

        age_min=13,
        age_max=65,

        paused=True,  # Default is False but let's keep this test ad paused
    )
    print('**** Done!')

    # Get the preview and write an html file
    preview = my_ad.get_ad_preview(params={
        AdPreview.Field.ad_format: AdPreview.AdFormat.right_column_standard
    })
    preview_filename = os.path.join(this_dir, 'preview_ad.html')
    preview_file = open(preview_filename, 'w')
    preview_file.write(
        "<html><head><title>Facebook Ad Preview</title><body>%s</body></html>"
        % preview.get_html()
    )
    preview_file.close()
    print('**** %s has been created!' % preview_filename)
```

Comment: If you got this code from GitHub, you might want to carefully check how this is working from wherever you got it. Because, clearly `AdAccount` is not declared anywhere in the code you are showing.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons `from ... import *` is considered hazardous...  If you had imported `AdAccount` explicitly, it would have obviously been imported.  If you had forgotten to import `AdAccount` explicitly, that would have also been obvious.  As it is, no one can _tell_ if you've imported the name `AdAccount` without reading through at least two other files.

Comment: I fixed the imports. They changed the libraries without updating docs and example codes.
`from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.ad import Ad
from facebookads.adobjects.adpreview import AdPreview
from facebookads.session import FacebookSession
from facebookads import FacebookAdsApi
`
But now I get this error:
  **File "test.py", line 55, in <module>
    bid_type=AdSet.BidType.cpm,
AttributeError: type object 'AdSet' has no attribute 'BidType'**

Comment: @TityBoi:  You should post that comment as an answer.  On Stack Overflow, you're allowed to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then (possibly after a waiting period) [accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/289641).  In contrast, you should post your new error as a new question... after first verifying that it's unrelated to the API change.  (You might also want to abandon that Git Hub code for a more up-to-date example, if you can find one.)